# How do I refactor this SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called `users` with a column called `activated_at`, and I want to count how many users have been activated by checking if the column is null or not. And then display them side by side like this:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Malaysia | Activated | Not Activated | Total |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| Malaysia |      5487 |           303 |  5790 | 
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
```

So this is my SQL:

```
select "Malaysia",
    (select count(*) from users where activated_at is not null and locale='en' and  date_format(created_at,'%m')=date_format(now(),'%m')) as "Activated",
    (select count(*) from users where activated_at is null and locale='en' and  date_format(created_at,'%m')=date_format(now(),'%m')) as "Not Activated",
    count(*) as "Total"
    from users 
    where locale="en"
    and  date_format(created_at,'%m')=date_format(now(),'%m');
```

In my code, I have to specify all the where statements three times, which is obviously redundant. How can I refactor this?

Regards,
MK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if MySql supports the CASE construct but I usually deal with this type of issue by doing something like,

```
select "Malaysia",
    SUM(CASE WHEN activated_at is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Activated",
    SUM(CASE WHEN activated_at is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "Not Activated",
    count(*) as "Total"
from users 
where locale="en" and  date_format(created_at,'%m')=date_format(now(),'%m');
```

Comment: I was going to say that but was checking my references. :)

Comment: See <http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case> for details on using CASE ... WHEN with MySQL.

Comment: MySQL coerces TRUE to 1, so you can just do e.g. SUM(activated_at IS NOT NULL), no CASE necessary.

Comment: This works, thanks Darel Miller! ^_^ (With just a little typo, you left a closing parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT( CASE WHEN activated_at IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Activated",
    COUNT( CASE WHEN activated_at IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Not Activated",
    COUNT(*) as "Total"
FROM users WHERE locale="en" AND date_trunc('month', now()) = date_trunc('month' ,created_at);
```

Comment: This is postgresql dialect. You may have to use IF THEN ELSE END in mysql.

Comment: @Nick: CASE is supported by MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work .. untested though:

```
select "Malaysia",
    (select count(*) from users2 where activated_at is not null) as "Activated",
    (select count(*) from users2 where activated_at is null) as "Not Activated",
    count(*) as "Total"
    from (select * from users where locale='en' and  date_format(created_at,'%m')=date_format(now(),'%m')) users2
```

p/s: Glad to see another Malaysian here ;)

EDIT: that won't work .. sorry .. use the CASE WHEN as suggested by others .. i wish i could delete this answer ..